# cordova ImagePicker plugins not working on android Marshmallow (PhoneGapBuild)

Tags: image, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

**In android 6, to access external storage you need to add additional permission**

Answer (score 1):

**After lots of R&D i got key answer**

***just add below code into config.xml***

set AndroidSDK version to 22.

```
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22"/>
```